# UIScrollView scroll enabling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm currently working on a Swift app that requires a few UIScrollViews, however I'm running into some problems making it work for all device sizes.

In this situation, I would have a content that would all appear on an iPhone 6, but not necessarily on an iPhone 4 or 5.

I've got a scroll view set up with some content and I would like to make it scrollable only if you don't see the full content.

Is there a way to perhaps detect if a certain element is visible?

Comment: The best way is to have a view added inside scrollview, and add all your components in that view instead of adding directly to scrollview. Keep the height of the view very big, fix the height and have a constraint as property for the view so that programatically you can adjust it. Now you calculate the height of view=contentview of scrollview by determining the last component position.y + height. That's it.

Comment: How would I get the y position and the height of the particular element?

Comment: It's quite simple, usually the last component in your scrollview will be added last in the view hierarchy. So you would do `id lastComponent=[[self.scrollView subviews] lastObject];` if you are adding components manually from XIB, just select the last component and change the order to front, so it will be last component, or you give an unique tag to the last element, and get it with tag `[self.scrollView viewWithTag:TAG];`

Comment: @iphonic, ok but what if the content is dynamic how to set then much bugger height?

Comment: @new2ios If your content is dynamic, still you can still pick the `id lastComponent=[[self.scrollView subviews] lastObject];` and you can determine the contentViewSize by `lastComponent.frame.origin.y+lastComponent.frame.size.height`

Comment: 10x for reply @iphonic

Answer (score 3):

the property `scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true` by default, and if the content is bigger than screen the user will be able to scroll.